# how can I understand if IMagick is installed?

Tags: php, centos6, imagemagick

I install Imagick according this tutorial:
http://www.imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php#unix

I used this code:

```
function alist ($array) {  //This function prints a text array as an html list.
  $alist = "<ul>";
  for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); $i++) {
    $alist .= "<li>$array[$i]";
  }
  $alist .= "</ul>";
  return $alist;
}
exec("convert -version", $out, $rcode); //Try to get ImageMagick "convert" program version number.
echo "Version return code is $rcode <br>"; //Print the return code: 0 if OK, nonzero if error.
echo alist($out); //Print the output of "convert -version"
```

And the result:

> Version return code is 0  Version: ImageMagick 6.9.0-0 Q16 x86_64
>   2014-12-24 http://www.imagemagick.org Copyright: Copyright (C)
>   1999-2014 ImageMagick Studio LLC Features: DPC OpenMP Delegates
>   (built-in): bzlib djvu fontconfig freetype jng jpeg lcms pangocairo
>   png tiff x xml zlib

And Also this code:

```
if(extension_loaded('imagick')) {
    echo 'Imagick Loaded';
}
else
    echo 'Imagick Not Loaded';
```

ANd the result:

```
Imagick Not Loaded
```

Also I couldn't see anything about Imagick (except: with-imagick=/usr/local') in phpinfo();

---

I am on CentOS 6.5 and php5.4 (a VPS server)

Comment: OS?  Version?  If Linux, distro?

Comment: I edited the question :)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
rpm -qa|grep ImageMagick
```

A blank response means it's not installed.

**Edit**: you may be getting hung up on getting a test to work, when you don't know that it's a good test.  You started off wanting `convert` to work - which is part of Image Magick - and you've confirmed that it does.  Can you tell us what your **real** problem is?

Comment: Thanks. It give me ImageMagick and ImageMagick-devel version...Do I must anything more to load class in php? I added 'extension = imagick.so
' in php.ini